# Как собрать текст из массива текстбоксов в строку?

Tags: c#, .net

добрый день. Может в шапке, тема немного размытая, но суть такова. Есть код, в Create создаются 100 текстбоксов, есть динамическая кнопка, хочу сделать событие "если кнопка нажата, то обработать значения в текстбоксах", обработка идет по событию клик, но не пойму как работать теперь с этими 100 текстбоксами. Для теста создал str1, в который будут записывать значения текстбоксов по первой строке, т.е. [0,1],[0,2]....[0,9]. Сделал вывод в одну из боксов, чтобы просто посмотреть результат. В результате было в текстбокс вывело

```
{System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: s System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, 
Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: sSystem.Windows.Forms.TextBox,
Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, 
Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, 
Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox,Text:}
```

Почему выводит System?????? :

https://paste.ofcode.org/CrN6ki4XKiZXXiFWZsbSfQ

Comment: потому что чтобы получить текст текстбокса нужно использовать `textbox.Text`, а не `textbox.toString()`.1. Перенесите код со стороннего ресурса в вопрос. 2. Не надо приводить весь код вашего класса, приводите минимальный пример на котором можно воспроизвести проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в строке 77. Вместо `str1 += tbArray[i, j];` вам нужно написать `str += tbArray[i, j].Text;`

Лучше, однако, в этом месте использовать `StringBuilder` вместо `string`:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < iLimit; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < iVariable; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            builder.Append(tbArray[i, j]);
        }
    }
}

tbArray[9, 9].Text = builder.ToString();
```